# Styling a stacked tab navigation in Twitter Bootstrap using a Bootbusiness theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootbusiness theme in  my Twitter Bootstrap website, and I am trying to create the stacked tab navigaton, as seen in the documentation of [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs) but whenever I try do it only appears as a List without style. And not styled as stacked button.

Here is my code in the HTML

```
<div >  
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
        <li class="active">List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
        <li>List Item 3</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The documentation contains <a> tags within the <li>, whereas yours does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an anchor inside `li` to get the styles

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/MgcDU/6153/)

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">List Item </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I really wasn't paying attention so I thought that the Theme itself was over riding the Bootstrap.css
Your answer has been most helpful @anpsmn